# In yii how to refresh array or how to delete previous entries of array

Tags: arrays, yii

I am working in Yii. I have following function in controller-

```
public function actiongetDnySubjectLink()
{
$contentTitleId=1;  
$category=new Dnycontentcategories();
$record=$category->getCheckByParentTitleId($contentTitleId);
foreach ($record as $rec)
    {
    echo "</br>"."Main category is: " .$rec->childTitleId;      
    $parent=$category->getCheckByContentTitleId($rec->childTitleId);
    echo $parent->englishTitle;     
    $record1=$category->getCheckByParentTitleId($rec->childTitleId);
    foreach ($record1 as $rec)
        {
        echo "subcategory is :".$rec->childTitleId;
        $child=$category->getCheckByContentTitleId($rec->childTitleId);
        $childlist[]=$child->englishTitle;
        echo $child->englishTitle;
        }
    echo CJSON::encode(array("parent"=>$parent->englishTitle,"child"=>$childlist))."</br>";
    }   
}
```

So i want to send parent and its children in `json` format. But `$childlist[]` array is storing all children of all parents. So how to refresh this array in order to store only current parents children . i.e. how to make array as empty before storing new parent's children . please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already tried, try initializing the array to null. May be something like this
`$childlist = array();`